# Interactive Brokers API - requesting delayed tick by tick data

Tags: api, interactive-brokers

I am trying to request delayed tick by tick data for Apple stock, just to have better understanding of how stream of data looks and how it arrives. Here is be code below:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
import time
from datetime import datetime
import threading


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.last_price_list = []

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def tickByTickAllLast(self, reqId, tickType, time, price, size, tickAtrribLast, exchange, specialConditions):
        print("Tick Price. Ticker Id:", reqId, "tickType:", TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), "Price:", price, 
                "tickAtrribLast:", tickAtrribLast, "specialConditions:", specialConditions,  end=' ')
        print("_______________________")
    

app = TestApp()

app.connect("127.0.0.1", 4002, 0)
    
    # allow time to connect to server
time.sleep(1)
    
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "AAPL"
contract.secType = "STK"
contract.exchange = "SMART"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"

app.reqMarketDataType(4)  # switch to delayed-frozen data if live is not available
app.reqTickByTickData(1 ,contract, "Last", 0, True)
#app.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])

api_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
api_thread.start()
```

It generates the following error:

```
Error:  -1   2104   Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
Error:  -1   2107   HMDS data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.ushmds
Error:  -1   2158   Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil
Error:  -1   2106   HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
Error:  1   10189   Failed to request tick-by-tick data.No market data permissions for ISLAND STK. Requested market data requires additional subscription for API. See link in 'Market Data Connections' dialog for more details.
```

I went through documentation (and still looking), but could not find any specific requirements, so I believe this is technical issue and I am not requesting data correctly.

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered on the [TWS API forum](https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topic/no_market_data_permissions/24243137).

Comment: @MatthewScarpino, ty, it looks like they are talking about historical data request (requires subscription). Here am asking for delayed market data, it should be free. My code works with `reqMktData`

Comment: My mistake. Judging by the [documentation](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/delayed_data.html) for delayed data, it looks like delayed data is only available through `reqMktData`. Also, the TWS API forum is a better place for TWS questions.

Comment: if you're inclined to try it in python, it's here. https://github.com/cosmoarunn/ib_insync_examples/blob/main/ticker-data.py